# SQL exception was not handled by user code

Tags: c#, sql

My code:

```
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        DataSet.UsersDataTable oUserDataTable =
            new DataSet.UsersDataTable();

        DataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter oUserTableAdapter =
            new DataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();

        oUserTableAdapter.FillUserByUserName(oUserDataTable, txtUserName.Text);

        if (oUserDataTable.Count!=1)
        {
            string strErrorMessage =
                "UserName Or Password Is Not Correct ! Please Try Again . . . ";
            DisplayErrorMessage(strErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        DataSet.UsersRow oUserRow = oUserDataTable[0];

        if (string.Compare(oUserRow.Password.Trim(),txtPassword.Text.Trim(),false)!=0)
        {
             string strErrorMessage =
                "UserName Or Password Is Not Correct ! Please Try Again . . . ";
             DisplayErrorMessage(strErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        if (oUserRow.IsUserActive==false)
        {
            string strInformationMessage =
                string.Format("Dear {0} You Should Not Login At This Time , Please Contact Support",txtUserName.Text);
            DisplayInformationMessage(strInformationMessage);
            return;
        }
```

I get an error:

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: update user page dosnt run

Comment: oUserTableAdapter.FillUserByUserName(oUserDataTable, txtUserName.Text);
 error on this line

Comment: What do you think `The server was not found or was not accessible.` means?

Comment: Google that error , it's very common and you will find resources

Comment: it is connection issue, check if your code can connect to DB or not

Comment: @Saif plz help me i have a big problem with my database

Comment: when i want to select server name..there shows me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all check if db connection can open, if yes, then is good to go, otherwise throw exception and check if the connection string is correct. Following code can help you for DB connection checking

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection"))
   {
      conn.Open();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Invalid Connection String");
}
```

add this code before this line `DataSet.UsersDataTable oUserDataTable =
            new DataSet.UsersDataTable();`